# Create SPOnline Modern Page with for Users to review and update project experience - and download page in Word

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, list-form, modern-pages, multiline-text-field

For our group consultants (all basic O365 and SP access)

1. We like to create a personal SP page in which they can fill and update their project experience (project CV).
2. These data will feed into a SP list (user record each row, with skills, project experience and dates in columns)
3. We like to download the actual project CV (Word/pdf) when required -> we think this can be done with Word templates or pdf extensions
4. We like to search on skills and project experiences and clients (taxonomy /managed properties -> we think this could be done with PnP Modern Search).

We have ideas on 3. and 4. but struggle with 1. and 2.

We checked for webparts on PnP and hoped for some light modifications - but could not find suitable solutions.
We are SP starters - willing to invest time.

Does anyone have suggestions - ideas - books - website/youtube examples  ?

thanks

Comment: Does it have to be a page? Maybe using a simple SharePoint list will suffice? In this case,  every project person can simply modify their item in the list.and no need to synchronize anything.  With some JSON list formatting, the list can look quite pretty.

Comment: We prefer a page for User Experience where User can fill out the text details. Those textinput stringvars could then with submit btn loaded in SP list

Comment: Thanks. We want a personal User profile page with info related to the User only - User can fill out and update with Submit btn to update the SP list. we are aware JSON list formatting - but is not our intention.

Comment: Would you be open to Power Apps? Otherwise, you will probably need create a custom SPFx solution.

Comment: The Users have M365 Business Basic - sonunsure if PowerApps work. Therefor i was focussing on SPFx solution too - but if PowerApps works within the package   at no extra costs ( eg Powerautomate plans) then we cld gobthat route.